# In C++ is it valid to pop_front() on a std::deque in a loop?

Tags: c++, stl, deque

If I have this code:

```
#include <deque>

int main()
{
    std::deque<int> d;

    d.push_back(1);
    d.push_back(2);
    d.push_back(3);
    d.push_back(4);
    d.push_back(5);

    for (std::deque<int>::iterator it = d.begin(); it != d.end(); it++)
    {
        d.pop_front();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering whether this is valid, because from what I've read, pop_front() invalidates any iterators or references to the element being removed. So if "it" is set to d.begin(), then we call d.pop_front(), then we execute "it++", since the call to pop_front() removed the element that "it" was referring to, doesn't that mean that it's invalid to then increment it?

Comment: It's possible if you increment the iterator in loop before pop_front(); So you don't hold the invalidated one.

Comment: But the question should be "what do you want to achieve."

Comment: If you want to empty out the `deque` you can use the [`std::dequeue::clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/clear) method.

Comment: The intention was to iterate over the deque and call pop_front() on each element that matches a certain condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is invalid, since `it` no longer points to a valid iterator once `pop_front()` is executed, thus `it++` will produce undefined behavior.

Comment: Could also suggest `while(!d.empty())`